# ignore-certificate-errors + headless puppeteer+google cloud

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-functions, chromium, puppeteer, headless

The website I am trying to access has ssl **certificate-errors**

I am using this version of puppeteer `"puppeteer": "1.13.0"`.

When I try to `await page.goto('http://bad_ssl_certificate_website')` I have timeout error on **google cloud** only.

> TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded:

However, It works perfectly fine **locally** on MAC.

I think the problem is ssl-certificate-errors for my website, because if I try with "google.com" it works okay in both environments.
I used https://www.sslshopper.com to check ssl certificates,and It mentioned this.

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by
>   following DigiCert's Certificate Installation Instructions for your
>   server platform. Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate
>   certificates.

When I was using older version of **puppeteer** I had problems **locally** as well. 
I saw the exactly the same error

> 'TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded:'

Updating to the newest version of puppeteer has fixed only running the puppeteer locally, but it has not fixed the puppeteer running on **google cloud**

This is how I setup puppeteer to lunch.

```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [
        "--proxy-server='direct://'",
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list',
        '--enable-features=NetworkService'
      ]
    });
```

I found some related issues:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=877075

Comment: Oh my godd!! Your config saved my life.
2 days , I was trying to make playwright works  from docker to my local self certified web site. 
I had to read chrome documentation to search for '-ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list' and get here.
This should be in the playwright and puppetter documentation for help

Answer (score 7):

Just turn  `.IgnoreHTTPSErrors = True` in the `LaunchAsync` constructor.

Example:

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions()
{
    Headless: true,
    IgnoreHTTPSErrors: true
});
```

Comment: Note that `Headless` and `IgnoreHTTPSErrors` must both start with lowercase (at least on my own installation)

Answer (score 3):

The `--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list` actually accepts a whitelist of public key hashes ignore certificate-related errors. So it is used like: `--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=jc7r1tE54FOO=`

[Chromium doc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/network/public/cpp/network_switches.cc?q=kIgnoreCertificateErrorsSPKIList&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=35)