# How to enable acceptInsecureCerts on Karate UI test

Tags: google-chrome, testing, karate, ui-testing

I'm trying to write a Karate UI test for my webpage which currently has a self signed certificate and hence blocked by the browser by default. [According to the documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriversession), when **acceptInsecureCerts** parameter is enabled, this check should be bypassed. But I can't find the correct syntax to pass this parameter to the driver. This is my (simplified) feature file:

```
Feature: browser automation 1

  Background:
    * def session = { capabilities: { acceptInsecureCerts: true } }
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true, showProcessLog: true, showBrowserLog: true, webDriverSession: '#(session)' }

  Scenario: load demo page
    Given driver 'https://127.0.0.1:8443/demo'
    * waitUntil('document.readyState == "complete"')
    * print 'page loaded'
    * screenshot()
    Then delay(2000).text('body')
```

When I run this, I get

```
13:31:25.237 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - << {"id":9,"result":{"result":{"type":"string","value":"Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold on, `chrome` is NOT webdriver based, so the `webDriverSession` will not apply. It would for `chromedriver`.

I did a quick search and the best I could find is this: [ignore-certificate-errors + headless puppeteer+google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55207690/143475)

So not sure if this works:

```
addOptions: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
```

Please report what you find so that it helps others ! Another reference is this, but not sure how up to date it is: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very quick answer! This works for me indeed:
`* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: [ '--ignore-certificate-errors' ] }`